# Magento 2 using mview.xml for tracking changes in custom table

Tags: magento2, adobe-commerce, mview

Magento indexing uses mview.xml to track changes in tables similarly, can we use mview.xml to track changes in custom table ? custom table doesn't do any indexing. I just want to track changes and do some operation after that. I want to do this tracking specifically when someone run sql statements on custom table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento's mview.xml (Materialized View XML) mechanism is specifically designed for indexing; however, it can be used to track changes in custom tables.

Make use of MySQL triggers instead.

There are several triggers that you can add to a table: `BEFORE INSERT`, `AFTER INSERT`, `BEFORE UPDATE`, `AFTER UPDATE`, `BEFORE DELETE`, and `AFTER DELETE`

Comment: Thank you @Ahmad for response, but native triggers won't allow me to translate data changes to the PHP file for further processing.